# Is it possible to change shortcuts for the add menu?

Tags: shortcut

I know you can add a shortcut, but can I change the shortcut on the Add Node menu? I would like to make the <kbd>S</kbd> key default to `Shader` instead of to `Search`. Can this be done? For example I want to be able to add a diffuse node using the key set: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

Comment: i think this is dynamically generated in this way : starting from the top  -> the shortcut is the first letter--> if it is taken then the second letter---> if it is taken the third .....

Comment: So then probably not possible?

Comment: if you can find the definition of this menu ( some .py file I hope ) move the "Search" entry down and the "Shader" will have the S shortcut

Comment: I might try that, I'll see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, blender GUI  was not designed with that in mind, it's something I've tried to do for a long time.
We can only hope or ask developers to give us facilities to customize menu shortcuts.

Here are some discussions that I started on this topic:

- [How to customize a Menu](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?320692-How-to-customize-this&highlight=)
- [Ayuda con los menus ( Spanish )](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?369230-Ayuda-con-los-menus&highlight=)

Personally I think it is quite necessary because many users require this. I think we should begin to wonder where can we make requests to the developers?

Comment: In future, please try to post in English, Stack Exchange tries to keep all content in one language. If you can't fluently write in English, we may be able to clarify parts for you. Post it, and we can edit it. And you can always rollback an edit if it changes the meaning :)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise i think it worked out, since probably most of us can at least understand, and chebhou was able to translate for those that weren't.

Comment: Yes, it just isn't a good regular practice I don't think. If the person posting can not write in english, it is certainly better to post a spanish post than none at all

Comment: bf-funboard is the mailing list for feature request.  The "fun"part is short for "functionality", http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard  bf- funboard es la lista de correo de solicitud de función . La parte "diversión" es la abreviatura de " funcionalidad "

Comment: "Google Translate" is useful for translating between languages.  Be careful to keep sentences short.  Also, avoid cultural-specific expressions.  Otherwise, the translator will likely return nonsense.  " Google Translate " es útil para la traducción entre idiomas. Tenga cuidado de mantener frases cortas . También, evitar expresiones específicas cultural. De lo contrario , el traductor es probable que regresar sin sentido .

Answer (score 1):

The characters underlined in the menus are the shortcuts. Your attempt at <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>D</kbd> is close, except the shortcut for Shader is h not s - use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>><kbd>H</kbd>><kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: I want to ***change*** it to `S`. The problem is that it is `H`. I want it like the change shader menu.